# Control panel in joomla 3 not showing properly - rest of backend ok

Tags: updates, joomla3.0

I just updated from 2.5.20 to 3.3.0

The front end seems fine

The backend after login takes me to this
[image: admin home page]

every other backend page is fine as is the front end

I have tried re-installing the administrator folder

What should I try to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I went through the admin modules, turning them off one by one. Turned out I needed to update one and all was well

Answer (score 1):

In my case was a module called "K2 Stats". Disabled and everything went fine